# Django: Form template: Input fields but not choose existing fields for ManyToMany Relations

Tags: python, django

I am creating a website for users to upload images... here's the form page:
[image: this is the screencap of the resulting page]

As from the screencap above, I cannot input any tags, I can only choose existing tags

My Question is: **What to add to the code so that users can input at most 10 tags when they have to upload an image**

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,  blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,  blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.FileField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + '-' + self.description

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ImageTag (models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image,  blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag,  blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'image/add/$', views.ImageCreate.as_view(), name='image-add'),
```

view.py

```
class ImageCreate (CreateView):
    model = Image
    fields = ['category', 'title', 'photo', 'description', 'tag']
```

image_form.html (I have deleted unrelated div)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% include 'imagebank/form-template.html' %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: please add your Tag class model.

Comment: but i want the tag being added by image uploader

Comment: You wrote `tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,  blank=True, null=True)` but you do not have define your tag model. For instance 

`class Tag(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ....`
then continue with your image model. 

Also do not forget to add tag model in your `admin.py` file

Comment: I defined already.... just that I thought it won't be useful, so i didnt put it up in the post..... I have updated the post now...... but the problem for the uploader to input tags is still there ><

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Did you insert any tags in your DB and then you can't see them?

Comment: no...i did not insert any tags...... I want users of the webpage to insert the tags for his image by typing them on the form
also, i want there to be a limit number of tags that a user can insert for every images, like 10